# Play Framework 1.4 - cache cause NullPointerException

Tags: java, caching, design-patterns, web-applications, playframework-1.x

when I try to access a historicized cache parameter and this has been canceled for some reason returns null.
Obviously this object is essential and causes a NullPointer.

The cache can be canceled for various reasons (ex: logout ..) .. but I need to handle these errors.

The object in question can not be recovered from DB because it is not present.

So I would need to understand if there is a pattern to be applied that allows you to manage these problems.

Comment: hello, thanks for answering but no ... my problem is design.
The application is multithreaded ... so if one of these empties the chache while the other tries to access the object then it causes the poblem

Comment: Hello, it is not clear what you expect, but I don't think there is any specific design pattern.
You should write some logic for this case depending on your application : either recreate the object and save it back on the cache or handle the fact that it can be null